# Response object value comes in array and some time object , how identify in my code?

Tags: android, json, gson

My response have many values, but one is filter object that are coming some time in array nad some time in object.

- How to find this one is object or array, i am using Gson in android.
- Comming in array like this,

  ```
  "filter": [
                {
                 "id": 3,
                 "level": "0",
                 "parent_id": 0,
                 "category_name": "Women",
                 "LEVEL1": [
                               {
                                "id": 130,
                                "level": "1",
                                "parent_id": 3,
                                "parent_name": "Women",
                                "category_name": "Saree",
                                "LEVEL2": [
                                    {
                                      "id": 152,
                                      "level": "2",
                                      "parent_id": 130,
                                      "parent_name": "Saree",
                                      "parent_parent_id": 3,
                                      "parent_parent_name": "Women",
                                      "category_name": "Party Wear"
                                    }
                          ]
                  }
               ]
  ```
- Some time coming like this,

  ```
  "filter": {
             "0": {
                   "attribute_title": "Brand",
                   "attribute_id": 1,
                   "childs": [
                              {
                               "child_attribute_name": "Ambica",
                               "child_attribute_id": 530,
                               "count": 38
                              }
                             ]
           }
  ```
- I am using Gson then how to identify in code,

Answer (score 0):

Using GSON API :

Create `JsonObject` from response json and pass it to following method :

```
    public Class<?> getJSONType(JsonObject jsObj) {
    GsonBuilder gBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = gBuilder.create();
    Object obj = gson.fromJson(jsObj.get("filter"), Object.class);
    if(obj instanceof List){
        return List.class;
    }else if(obj instanceof Map){
        return Map.class;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here I have considered that filter is top level element in your JSON.
The code `jsObj.get("filter")` should be modified to reach up to correct location.